# How can I detect when the "Save as type:" combo box changes using GetSaveFileName on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, combobox, save

I'm using [`GetSaveFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a Save As dialog in a Windows application. I'd like to catch when the "Save as type:" combo box changes and get its current index, but I'm not sure how.

With a combo box I add myself, I can get messages in the callback (`lpfnHook`) in the `OPENFILENAME` struct that we've handed off, and look for the ID of the combo box and the `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification. But I don't know what the ID of the "Save as type:" combo box is, or even if we're allowed access to it in the same way.

Is there a way to detect when the "Save as type:" combo box changes and to get its current index before `GetSaveFileName` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a callback using `lpfnHook` you will get [`CDN_TYPECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notifcation messages when the user changes the type.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just be sure to pay close attention to the documentation: "The system sends this notification only if the dialog box was created using the `OFN_EXPLORER` value."